# Accesing $this outside foreach loop Jquery

Tags: jquery, foreach, this

```
jQuery('.webform-component-checkboxes').each(function(){
    var height = heightAdjustment(jQuery(this));
    console.log(height);
});

function heightAdjustment(variable){
    var temp = 0;
    var elements = {};
    var max;
    jQuery(variable).find('.form-checkboxes .form-type-checkbox label.option').each(function() {
        max = jQuery(this).parent().css('height');
        temp = temp > max ? temp : max ;
        elements = this;    
    });

    elements.parent('div').siblings().css('height',temp);
}
```

I am using this code, but the value of 'elements' become empty outside the loop. but inside it's working.

Help me out !

Comment: You just said it, elements are only available in function scope.

Comment: You don't need to re-wrap `variable` in a jQuery tag, as you're already passing it a jQuery object. Also, `elements` is a regular object, not a collection of jQuery elements, so your last line will fail.

Comment: What should `elements` contain? What is not working?

Comment: element should contain whole object that $this is inside

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. No need to re-wrap `variable` as it's already a jQuery object.
2. Your `elements` is a regular object, rather than a collection of jQuery elements. If you want this to store a list of jQuery elements, simply declare it as a variable and set it to a selector.
3. You're doing `console.log(height)`, but your function `heightAdjustment()` doesn't return anything. I've added `return temp;` so that the function returns the height to which the affected elements were set.

```
var elements;

jQuery('.webform-component-checkboxes').each(function(){
    var height = heightAdjustment(jQuery(this));
    console.log(height);
});

function heightAdjustment(variable){
    var temp = 0;
    var max;
    elements = variable.find('.form-checkboxes .form-type-checkbox label.option');
    elements.each(function() {
        max = jQuery(this).parent().css('height');
        temp = temp > max ? temp : max ;   
    });

    elements.parent('div').siblings().css('height',temp);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: but now its giving output undefined for this ,
     console.log(elements.css('height'));

Comment: Because `elements` is declared within the scope of `heightAdjustment();` and is not available outside. Where are you calling that? See my latest edit, perhaps it solves your issue.

Comment: I am not able to access parents of elements variable.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve instead of vaguely pointing out things you "cannot do"? It would be much easier to fix your code if we had any idea what you were trying to do.